# x11: Disable mouse

Tags: mouse, x11

I use x11 and awesome as my WM.  I would like to completely disable the mouse, that is mouse clicks, mouse wheel, mouse movement, display of the cursor, etc.

Is there an easy way (I would prefer a disable/enable bash script)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

For the mouse, proceed as follows. Use `xinput list` to find out your mouse devices. Disable with

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```

to enable it again, type

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1
```

where 12 is the id of your device. Given that the mouse cursor disappears if mouse is inactive, you need not to worry about that (if it doesn't, you can use `unclutter`)

Comment: OMG, so nice, especially with Ratpoison WM.

Answer (score 6):

After reading the answer from @January and the man page of `xinput` I noticed a shorter version:

```
xinput --enable 12
xinput --disable 12
```

where 12 is the id of your device

Comment: How do I find out if a device is disabled or not?

Answer (score 4):

Another answer to your question is to unload the module that is responsible for.

```
sudo modprobe -rvf psmouse
```

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately i have 2 built-in psmouse and i only want to disable one