# Wireless Mouse problem

Tags: wireless, mouse

I have two computers in two rooms next to eachother, with two wireless mice that have their own recievers. 
The problem is that the reciever on my computer is picking up the wireless signal from the mouse on the other room, so it is also moving on my computer when it's being used ~.~

On Windows I was able to go to device manager and disable the second mouse from device manager. [So it only picks up one mouse]
But I'm not sure how I can do it on Lubuntu. [I use Lubuntu 14.04 LTS]

Any idea ? ;/

Comment: Does the method in this question work for you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/199271/x11-disable-mouse

Comment: Bah, I just noticed it doesnt last after restarting though, I guess I'll just add it to lightdm.conf and it should work, trying now...

Comment: Ok, made a script and made it run at startup and it works now ~ thanks.