# How to completely disable / delete the mouse on Ubuntu?

Tags: xorg, devices, xinput, input

I tried a few approaches like `xinput list` and `xinput disable` but still can't get to completely disable the mouse (touchpad or any other pointer input) on my Ubuntu machine. Does anyone know how to do that? I basically want to have only the keyboard enabled.

[Error I am currently encountering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5dOC.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [x11: Disable mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199271/x11-disable-mouse)

Comment: No. I had actually been to that page before I asked it here. Here is the return:
leo@desktop:~$ sudo xinput --disable 2
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22